# Github Action won't run until manually enabled

Tags: github, github-actions

I need to create a bunch of repositories programmatically using from a local template.
I have a `.github/workflows/build.yml` with `on: [push]`. However, Github Action won't run, even if I wait for several minutes after repo creation or commit and push several commits.

If I go to `Actions` tab, I see this:

[image]

If I click on `Enable Actions on this repository`, tab changes to this:

[image]

And if I make a push after this - Action works, without any changes to `build.yml`.
Is this expected behavior?

If yes, how can I automate this? There doesn't seem any corresponding endpoint in [Actions API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions)

Answer (score 2):

Well, since it appears that no API call can be used to enable Actions in organization repository, I had to resort to `Selenium` and automate clicking :\

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour.

You can use e.g. the REST API to activate GitHub actions for a repository. Replace OWNER and REPO with the values to specify the repository. Replace USERNAME and TOKEN with the details of your personal access token (PAT).

> You must authenticate using an access token with the `repo` scope to use this endpoint.

```sh
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/permissions \
  -d '{"enabled":true,"allowed_actions":"all"}'
  -u USERNAME:TOKEN
```

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#set-github-actions-permissions-for-a-repository

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't for the life of me google it!
However, this doesn't seem to be working; github returned code 204 but actions still won't run, button is still there.

Comment: Strange. The only thing that comes to mind is that this might not work for organizations. Is your repository part of an organization?

Comment: Yes, it is.. I used API URL scheme  `api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/actions/permissions`

Comment: Then check your organizations settings for GitHub Actions (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#get-github-actions-permissions-for-an-organization). Is it configured to only allow Actions for selected repositories? Then you probably have to use https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#set-selected-repositories-enabled-for-github-actions-in-an-organization.

Comment: No, `Allow all actions and reusable workflows` is selected for All repositories